# Reverse values of alternate nodes of the tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

Given a Perfect Binary Tree, reverse the alternate level nodes of the binary tree.

> Given tree:
>
> ```
>           a
>
>        /     \
>       b       c
>     /  \     /  \
>    d    e    f    g
>   / \  / \  / \  / \
>   h  i j  k l  m  n  o
> ```
>
> Modified tree:
>
> ```
>           a
>
>        /     \
>        c       b
>      /  \     /  \
>     d    e    f    g
>    / \  / \  / \  / \
>   o  n m  l k  j  i  h
> ```

This question is attributed to GeeksForGeeks. The difference between this and the one solved by me previously [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55850/given-a-perfect-binary-tree-reverse-the-alternate-level-nodes-of-the-binary-tre), is that in this case the "values" can be changed rather than the actual nodes. Looking for code review, optmizations and best practices.

```
public class SwapTreeLevelsValues<T> {

    private TreeNode<T> root;

    public SwapTreeLevelsValues(List<T> nodes) {
        create(nodes);
    }

    private void create (List<T> items) {        
        root = new TreeNode<>(items.get(0));

        final Queue<TreeNode<T>> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode<T>>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode<T> current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode<T>(items.get(left));
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode<T>(items.get(right));
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static class TreeNode<T> {
        private TreeNode<T> left;
        private T item;
        private TreeNode<T> right;

        TreeNode(T item) { 
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Given a perfect binary tree, swaps the even levels.
     * For an non-perfect binary tree, results are unpredictable.
     */
    public void reverseAlternateLevels() {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The root cannot be null"); 
        }
        reverse(root, root, true);
    }


    private void reverse (TreeNode<T> node1, TreeNode<T> node2, boolean level) {
        if (node1 == null) {
            return;
        }

        reverse(node1.left, node2.right, !level);

        if (node1 == root) return;

        if (level) {
            T temp = node1.item; 
            node1.item = node2.item;
            node2.item = temp;
        }


        reverse(node1.right, node2.left, !level);
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hashCompute(root, 0);
    }

    public int hashCompute (TreeNode<T> node, int item) {
        if (node == null) return item;
        item = 31 * hashCompute (node.left, item) + node.hashCode();
        return hashCompute(node.right, item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SwapTreeLevelsValues<T> other = (SwapTreeLevelsValues<T>) obj;
        return equal(root, other.root);
    }


    private boolean equal(TreeNode<T> node1, TreeNode<T> node2) {
        if (node1 == null && node2 == null) return true;
        if (node1 == null || node2 == null) return false;
        if (node1.item != node2.item) {
            return false;
        }

        return equal(node1.left, node2.left) && equal(node1.right, node2.right);
    }
}

public class SwapTreeLevelValuesTest {


    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31); ;
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16); 
        SwapTreeLevelsValues<Integer> stlv1 = new SwapTreeLevelsValues<>(list1);
        stlv1.reverseAlternateLevels();
        SwapTreeLevelsValues<Integer> stlv2 = new SwapTreeLevelsValues<>(list2);
        System.out.println(stlv2.equals(stlv2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your omission of a generic type in `new TreeNode<>` intentional?

Comment: yes it is intentional

Answer (score 3):

A minor bug: You get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for an empty list in `SwapTreeLevelsValues.create(List<T> items)`. You don't have a comment stating you need to input a list containing at least something. Consider returning `IllegalArgumentException` and adding a comment.

---

I had to do a double take here:

```
final int left = 2 * i + 1;
final int right = 2 * i + 2;
```

It only made sense after looking at the diagram. Still, you're doing a calculation twice... why not do it like this?

```
final int left = 2 * i + 1;
final int right = left + 1;
```

That said, you might wanna put a comment there. It's not a trivial line of code.

Looking up a bit...

```
final int half = items.size() / 2;

for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
    if (items.get(i) != null) {
```

You're not modifying `items`. Is it possible for `items.get(i)` to not return `null` once it has once returned null? If not, why not break out of the for loop, rather than going through the remaining loops? (Performance when dealing with large TreeMaps).

I can't find anything else, really.